# How do I do a stacked bar chart as a drilldown to a stacked bar chart?

Tags: highcharts

I just can't see how to stack the series for the drilldown. Do I add the drilldown chunks as:

```
drilldown = [{name: 'bob',
              data: [series1, series2,series3],
              id: drilldown_id}]
```

Currently [the docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#drilldown.series) seems to indicate to add all the series in the data series, but I'm not getting it working. Currently don't have a jsfiddle as everything I'm doing is in Python, but can provide one if need be.

Update:
I understand from the docs that the series plotoptions for the drilldown are inherited from the parent series -- please correct me if this is wrong. I currently have multiple series with the same id, but they are not stacking currently.

Comment: Could you post live example, like jsFiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NULTY/1074/  is the closest thing. Obviously this uses quite heavily customised plot options  and the drilldown doesn't go to a stacked series.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using [drill down to multiple series from multiple series demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/drilldown/multi-series/) it is possible to change stacking to `normal` and get drilldown to stacked columns.

JSFiddle 1: http://jsfiddle.net/rxjutt6v/

Using [async drill down demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/drilldown/async/) and `addSingleSeriesAsDrilldown` with `applyDrilldown` it is possible to get multiple series in drilldown when drilling into single series point.

JSFiddle 2: http://jsfiddle.net/49q18Lp3/1/